# change file extension (ods to csv) and get an output for each file

Tags: perl

I have many files in ods format and I want to convert them to csv format by a perl code. Also, I have a perl code which replace some characters by others, but for each file I have to tape its name, so I want to be able to proceed a bunch of files at the same time, and to have an output for each file with the modifications. 
So far my code looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


my @repertoire =glob('/home/test/Desktop');


# warn Dumper \@repertoire;
foreach my $fileName (@repertoire)
{
    open(IN, "<$fileName") or die "Can't read file '$fileName' [$!]\n";
    print "$fileName\n" ;
    @files=<IN>;
    close(IN);

    foreach $file (@files)
    {
     $file =~ /(\x{0625}\x{0646}\b.+?)\./[[    ]]/g)
     my $new=$file;
   print $new;
   print "\n";
   system("cp @repertoire/$file @repertoire/$new") # copy output of each file in  '/home/test/Desktop'
    }
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile under `use strict;`

Answer (score 1):

Besides missing closing `"` in your `glob` call, you should add a wildcard to the path, so the glob can really return a list:

```
my @repertoire = glob '/home/test/Desktop/*.ods';
```

Also, try to use a more "telling" variable names: `@files` suggests a list of files, but is in fact a list of lines of a file.

What exactly is your question?

Comment: My code can read the content of the files and the regex work well. My question now is: how can I print the output of each file in the same directory. See my code of my post, I re-edited it.